# Issue importing python soundfile library - OSError: library not found: 'sndfile'

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, redhat

I am hosting a python flask service that does audio computations using soundfile library. It runs fine on my local but when i host it on redhat, i see the below issue. Any suggestions -

```
 from soundfile import read
  File "/apollo/env/AQTAudioPoProService/lib/python3.4/site-packages/soundfile.py", line 265, in <module>
    _snd = _ffi.dlopen('sndfile')
  File "/apollo/env/AQTAudioPoProService/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 139, in dlopen
    lib, function_cache = _make_ffi_library(self, name, flags)
  File "/apollo/env/AQTAudioPoProService/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 769, in _make_ffi_library
    backendlib = _load_backend_lib(backend, libname, flags)
  File "/apollo/env/AQTAudioPoProService/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cffi/api.py", line 757, in _load_backend_lib
    raise OSError("library not found: %r" % (name,))
OSError: library not found: 'sndfile'
```

Tried installing libsndfile

```
[dshanm@aqts-popro-1a-05885815] var/output/logs% sudo yum install libsndfile
Loaded plugins: priorities, security
Setting up Install Process
No package libsndfile available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 1):

The soundfile Python module depends on the `libsndfile` native library. You'll need to install it on your operating system:

```
$ yum install libsndfile
```

Comment: `[dshanm@aqts-popro-1a-05885815]/var/output/logs% sudo yum install libsndfile`
`Loaded plugins: priorities, security`
`Setting up Install Process`
`No package libsndfile available.`
`Error: Nothing to do`
I get the above. any idea?

Comment: @Mureinik, still no  result! it says 'pkg not available'